# Shopping cart for authorized for a month, and for unauthorized for several hours Laravel

Tags: laravel, session, cookies, cart

I have a session lifetime of 120 minutes in my Laravel config. How can you implement that for authorized users the goods are stored longer (for example, a month), and for unauthorized users, as usual, 120 minutes? I made a cart through the Session facade.

If you need me to share the shopping cart code, please let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sessions in Laravel are based on a cookie, generally named `laravel_sesion`.

The session lifetime is defined to 120 by default in `config/session.php`.
You can store your cart into the session data, and try update this lifetime at runtime (in your controller for exemple) using :

```php
if (Auth::check()) {
  config(['session.lifetime' => 60 * 24 * 30 ]); // 1 month for authorized user
};
```

I personnally don't think that's a good idea.

I would rather store the Cart into a database, with `user_id` and `expires_at` columns, and then store into a cookie (or in the session) the `card` identifier.

When the cart is updated, the `expires_at` date should also be updated to a future date (ie now + 120s for unauthorized user, or now + 1 month for authorized users)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But what about storing in the session for unauthorized users and in the DB for authorized users? Is this the right way? And is it difficult to implement?